# mysql query for getting all rooms which are not booked between a date range not giving expected results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

I'm creating a booking system and it has 2 tables

rooms

```
id  | name          | no_of_rooms   
1   | Lake View     | 4
2   | Royale        | 2
3   | Sky View      | 6
```

bookings

```
id |room_id     | start             | end           | total_rooms
4  |1           | 2015-08-13        | 2015-08-14    | 2
5  |2           | 2015-08-20        | 2015-08-22    | 1
6  |2           | 2015-08-01        | 2015-08-13    | 1
```

and when creating a new booking on the search page I want to find the available rooms that is available within this date range

SEARCH VALUES
start  : 2015-08-11 
end    : 2015-08-12

Expected Result

```
id | name       | no_of_rooms       | available_rooms
1  | Lake View  | 4                 | 4
2  | Royale     | 2                 | 1
3  | Sky View   | 6                 | 6
```

Result I got

```
id  | name          | no_of_rooms   | available_rooms
1   | Lake View     | 4             | 0
2   | Royale        | 2             | 1
3   | Skyview       | 6             | 0
```

Here's the code I wrote for room availability

```
SELECT 
    r.id, 
    r.name,
    r.no_of_rooms,
    IFNULL(sum(b.total_rooms),0) as available_rooms
FROM rooms r
LEFT JOIN bookings b ON r.id = b.room_id AND 
(
    (b.start <= "2015-08-11" AND b.end >= "2015-08-11")
    OR
    (b.start <= "2015-08-12" AND b.end >= "2015-08-12")
)
GROUP BY r.id
```

I also don't want the to show unavailable rooms.No matter what I tried the results are completely wrong.Hope you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT r.id AS roomID, r.name, r.no_of_rooms, 
       r.no_of_rooms - COALESCE(t.bookedRooms,0) AS available_rooms
FROM rooms AS r
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT room_id, SUM(total_rooms) AS bookedRooms
   FROM bookings
   WHERE `start` < '2015-08-14' AND `end` > '2015-08-11'
   GROUP BY room_id ) AS t
ON r.id = t.room_id
WHERE r.no_of_rooms - COALESCE(t.bookedRooms,0) > 0
```

The key to finding booked rooms for the specified period is the following predicate:

```
`start` <= '2015-08-12' AND `end` >= '2015-08-11'
```

The above gets all rooms whose booking period *overlaps*, even for one day, with the specified period.

Using a `GROUP BY` on `room_id` we can get *the total sum* of booked rooms per `room_id` for the period specified.

To get the expected result set, we can just do a `LEFT JOIN` with the derived table of booked aggregates and simply subtract the sum of booked rooms from the number of available rooms.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95ab7/7)

Comment: tried it but it doesn't work
I don't know how to format code in comments section could you please look in to this ?
http://pastebin.com/WUBJAhZp

Comment: please see my pastebin code
if I change the total_rooms of the booking 4 with the room_id 1 to 4 (all rooms) the result when I search between the date `start` <= '2015-08-13' AND `end` >= '2015-08-14' should give 0 avaiable_rooms for that room currently it gives 3 available rooms.

Comment: for room 1 it should not be shown in that date-range because all is occupied and for room 2 it should show 1 rooms as available

this is the result I get
http://i.imgur.com/keCvEXk.png

I aplogize for my bad English but I hope you will be able to understand it if not should I post in sqlfiddle later?

Comment: @user3407278 I think I have fixed both issues. Please check the edit I made.

Comment: It seems to be working now.I'm checking all cases.Thanks a lot @Giorgos Betsos.Thank you so much